# BES Administration WSDL Generation Documentation Incorrect

Tags: c#, blackberry, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to administer my BES 5.0 servers using C# and the following URL seems to not only tell me to generate a WSDL for an incorrect namespace (does not exist) but it also generates collisions.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/16633/Generate_the_client_proxy_925487_11.jsp

What is the correct way to set up the WSDL for the BES admin api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is the following command, one line, with the FQDN of the server:

```
wsdl.exe /sharetypes /out:C:\Temp\proxy.cs  https://myFQDN/baaws/core/ws?wsdl https://myFQDN/baaws/core/wsutil?wsdl https://myFQDN/baaws/emailexchange/ws?wsdl  https://myFQDN/baaws/dispatcher/ws?wsdl
```

Alternate WSDL for Groupwise: (append) baaws/emailgroupwise/ws?wsdl

Alternat WSDL for LotusNotes: (append) baaws/emaildomino/ws?wsdl